# Fortigate Radius Reply Message

Tags: fortigate, radius

I have setup a Microsoft NPS radius server for my Fortigate firewall and i want to display reason of fail login to the users in Fortigate fail page (for example display "You can not login during this hour of day" in fail page when user tries to login in invalid times). How can i do this?